# In computer graphics, why is everything an approximation?

Tags: graphics, rendering, modeling, approximation

While going through some computer graphics exam questions, I found this one and I was wondering what everyone thinks the answer is:
Given the statement: “In Computer Graphics, everything is an approximation”,
explain what you understand by this, in terms of modelling and rendering.

Answer (score 2):

We can't have 100% quality in our models or lighting because the computational power and memory required to store and render that data would be huge.

Just imagine simulating photon per photon-lighting in a scene with literally billions of particles, and how these photons would be colliding and absorbed by atoms and molecules - in real time. It would basically be impossible because of the power needed.

Comment: Also, there are a lot of material we don't have an analytical model for, and just the nature of the computers we use make allmost all calculations an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Tokfrans said, think about mesh structures they are all discrete versions of a surface in which the surface is approximated by a set of triangles(polygons) the curve is the same story as we use a poly line to represent it. Even if the curve is infinitely smooth, we usually render and represent it with a set of connected lines.